Tensor products of modules and extension of scalars: why is it nontrivial?
In Atiyah-Macdonald, the following construction is described: Given two rings $A,B$ and $N$ a $B$-module and $f:A\to B$ a homomorphism, we can make $B,N$ into $A$-modules by defining $a\cdot x=f(a)x$. This makes sense to me.
However they go on to describe the $B$-module $N_B= B\otimes_A N$. I can see that, regarded as an $A$-module, this is usually different from $N$, but if we regard it as a $B$-module with the scalar multiplication given by $b'(b\otimes n)=(bb'\otimes n)$ then I get confused.
Exercise 13 asks you to

Show that the homomorphism $g:N\to N_B$ which maps $y$ to $1\otimes y$ is injective and that $g(N)$ is a direct summand of $N_B$

but if $y\to 1\otimes y$ is a $B$-module homomorphism, then we would need to have $by\to b(1\otimes y)=b\otimes y=1\otimes by$, which would make the map an isomorphism. So are we saying that $g$ is an $A$-module homomorphism? But then why do we give $B\otimes_A N$ a $B$-module structure and refer to it as a $B$-module?

Tensor product is over $A$, not over $B$, this is your mistake. The q is a duplicate for sure. Please can someone else find the correct duplicate?

Are any of the answers here or here useful?

@MartinBrandenburg Obviously $N_B=B\otimes_A N$ is over $A$ not over $N$, so a priori it is just an $A$-module, but then you can add a $B$-module structure to $N_B$ as described in my question.

@SammyBlack Yes I think that second question answers it since they specify $g$ is not necessarily a $B$-module homomorphism, but then I'm confused as to why specify that $N_B$ is a $B$-module at all?

I don't think the $B$-module structure is particularly relevant for this specific problem, but in general the fact that $N_B$ is a $B$-module is the whole point of the construction. This will make more sense once you see extension of scalars used in practice.

@KenanskiBowspleefi Got it, thank you!
